# What kind of damage could one do with a payment gateway API login and transaction key?

Tags: security, payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net

Currently, I'm in the process of hiring a web developer who will be working on a site that processes credit cards. While he won't have the credentials to log into the payment gateway's UI he will have access to the API login and transaction key since it's embedded in the application's code.

I'd like to be aware of all the "what if" scenarios pertaining to the type of damage one could do with that information. Obviously, he can process credit cards but the money goes into the site owner's bank account so I'm not sure how much damage that could cause. Can anyone think of any other possible scenarios?

UPDATE: The payment gateway being used is Authorize.net.

Comment: Which payment gateway are you using, some of us may already have experience with it ?

Comment: The payment gateway being used is Authorize.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do they really need access to your production sites?

Don't store the key in your code, store it in your production database, or on a file on the production server.

Comment: Having programmed against payment gateways that can be a little hard.  Most offer a test api key that can do much of the testing, but if something's not working and I need to troubleshoot, not having the same config as on the production server can make it pretty difficult. Just sayin'.

Comment: So implement an interface around it yourself. This is what we do, we have our own wrapper around the payment gateway, applications talk to this wrapper. In dev, it returns canned responses, in production, it really connects to the payment gateway.

Answer (score 3):

Some good answers here, I'll just add that you'd probably have some trouble with PCI.
PCI-DSS specifically dictates separation of duties, isolation of production environments from dev/test, protection of encryption keys from anyone who does not require it, and more. 
As @Matthew Watson said, rethink this, and dont grant production access to developers.

As an aside, if he can access the API directly, how do you ensure that "the money goes into the site owner's bank account"? Not to mention access to all that credit card data...

Answer (score 1):

If the developer gets access to the raw credit card numbers that can become a bigger problem as your site can be associated with fraudulent activity, assuming the developer is a bad apple.  (They could redirect account numbers, CCV, expiration date to another site, though this should be spottable through network tools and a comprehensive code review.)

Does the API perform the "$1.00" charge (or "$X.XX") to verify that a credit card can be charged a certain amount (and thus returning the result to the caller, such as "yes" or "no")?  If so, it could be used to automate the validation of credit card account numbers traded on the Internet and abuse of such a system could lead back to you.

Answer (score 1):

With any gateway I have worked with, the payment processor ties the API key to the specific IP or IP range of the site of the merchant. With that said, unless the malicious(?) code in question is executed on the same server as the merchant - there shouldn't be any security concerns in that regard.

If this is not the case for your merchant site - contact them and ask if this is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Does the payment gateway allow for reversal of charges? If so there is the possibility of a number of scams being run.

Answer (score 1):

Does the site process refunds?  Will it ever in the future?

If we're talking about nefarious uses, then the site owner might be investigated if lots of unauthorized purchases are made.  How would that affect **you** if the owner is investigated?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that this developer will have access to the customer cards detail in which case the customers privacy may be compromised. You might consider wording the contract appropriately to make sure that this angle is covered.

However the main point is that if you're working on a sensitive project/information it's better for you to find people you could trust. Hiring a software house to do the job may save you some sleep later on.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, it is best that you never store this type of information in plain text. Usually people take this as second-hand knowledge for credit card numbers (Sadly, only because of legal reasons), but any sort of private data that you don't want others with database/source-code access viewing should be encrypted. You should store the account information somewhere in a well encrypted format, and you should provide a test account for your developers to use on their development workstations. This way, only people with server access are able to see even the encrypted information.

This way, you can have a database on the developer's workstation with the test account's API information stored (hopefully encrypted) in it's local database, but when the code is mirrored onto the production server it will still use the live, real gateway information stored on the production server's database without extra code/configuration.

With this said, I don't think that a programmer with API authentication details can do too much. Either way, it's not worth the risk - in my opinion.

Hope this help.

PS: If something bad does end up happening, you can always generate a new key in the web interface on authorize.net after you've taken the precautions to make sure it wont happen again.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of Authorize.Net they would not be able to do credits towards their own credit cards since Authorize.Net only allows this to be done on transactions performed through them within the last six months. The only exception being allowed if you are granted an exception for unlinked refunds. If you have signed the proper paperwork for this and someone has your API login and transaction key then can then process credits towards their own credit cards. The only way for you to catch this would be to monitor your statements carefully.

To help mitigate this you should change your transaction key immediately upon completion of the work they perform for you. That would render the key they have useless after 24 hours.